# How leaflet js load tiles from file system

Tags: javascript, leaflet

suppose tiles are store in file system like below image
[image]

roughly seen this url http://build-failed.blogspot.in/2012/11/zoomable-image-with-leaflet.html

### see the code

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
        L.tileLayer('http://localhost/tiles/eso/0/0/0.png', {
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 6,
            attribution: 'Testing',
            tms: true
        }).addTo(map);
```

from the above code it seems that loading tile 0/0/0.png means refer one tile. so my question is how leaflet will load so many tiles because this url http://localhost/tiles/eso/0/0/0.png refer one tile.

the above code is right?

the above code can load bunch of tiles ?

what `setView([0, 0], 2);` doing ? what is the meaning of `0,0 and 2` what does it mean ?

### also tell me what the below code is trying to say

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
        L.tileLayer('eso/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 6,
            attribution: 'ESO/INAF-VST/OmegaCAM',
            tms: true
        }).addTo(map);
```

in the above code we do not mention any value for z or for y or x ?

what approach i need to follow in real life ?
do i need to specify value or leaf will provider value for z,y, and x at run time ?

please let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Above code is wrong. Test it and you will see always the same repeated 0/0/0 tile.

2) Above code **cannot** load bunch of tiles, or actually it creates bunch of tiles all having the same image.

3) `setView([0, 0], 2)` centers the map view on coordinates point latitude 0 degree, longitude 0 degree, and with zoom level 2 (zoom level 0 being the entire planet in 1 tile).

4) Refer to [Leaflet documentation about raster Tile Layer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer):

> {z} — zoom level, {x} and {y} — tile coordinates.

The first argument of `L.tileLayer`is the **`urlTemplate`**. The `{z}`, `{x}` and `{y}` texts are replaced by Leaflet by the target tile coordinates. For example, you can go to [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and right click on any tile (anywhere on the base map), select "Open image" (or "View image") and the browser will show only the particular tile with its exact URL, where z, x and y have been adjusted by Leaflet to point to that particular tile.

The background system is that tiles are arranged in a [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) structure, assuming zoom level 0 corresponds to the entire map fitting in a single tile (i.e. 0/0/0). Then for the next higher zoom level, each tile is subdivided into 4 child tiles. And so on.

So in the example folder structure you exhibit in your question, tiles 1/0/0 and 1/0/1 are the left half of tile 0/0/0. Tile 1/0/0 is the top left corner, tile 1/0/1 is the bottom left corner.

Again, all this is automatically managed by Leaflet, provided that your tiles follow this Quadtree arrangement (whether in folders or within their file name, like for Zoomify).

Answer (score 0):

ghyb's answer for 1,2, and 3 are completely correct, you might want to vote that answer up.

> ...also tell me what the below code is trying to say

On your second question, ghybs is also completely correct - I will add to it from the perspective of someone who needed a simpler introduction.  In addition to diving into the TileLayer code, you might start by googling 'slippy map' to get many intro-level conceptual overviews.  A good and popular technical intro to slippy map tilenames and how to derive them from map coordinates, along with code examples in several languages, can be found in [the openstreetmap documentation here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).  These will definitely help you wrap your head around the TileLayer code.

> what approach i need to follow in real life ? do i need to specify
>   value or leaf will provider value for z,y, and x at run time ?

Leaflet and other libraries plug in the value of x,y,z as described by ghybs, based on the where you move and zoom on the map.  They produce the values, and the request is made to the appropriate folders.  In real life, you only need the folders with the right images (produced by a program that generates tiled images into those folder structures) - either on your computer, on a server - or, what is far more common, by using a web map server that delivers the images requested at x/y/z.  Examples include geoserver, mapserver, mapnik, and many online services like google maps, openstreetmap, bing, etc.